# Trying to search a text file and display output. Console app

Tags: c#

Develop a program to parse a data file and present the output to the user based on supplied command line arguments.
The applicant will be provided with a text file that contains medical reports for patients (medicalreports.txt). Your application should read this file, and parse the individual fields for each record and store them in memory. 
The program should also accept the following command line arguments, and print the saved data based on the argument(s) supplied.

Argument    Required    Value   Explanation
-file   Yes  The location of the input file
-sort   No   Should print all the saved data to the console sorted ascending by the field name that is supplied. So if the argument is –sort PatientID, print all the data, sorted by the PatientID field.
-search No    Print all the reports that contain the supplied search value. So if –search Smith is supplied, the output is all the reports with the word Smith in any of the fields.

Note that only the first argument is mandatory. If the evaluator does not supply any other arguments, the program must merely print the data in the original order. The print formatting is up to the applicant, but it should be easy to read.

```
For example, if the evaluator uses the following command:
Program1.exe –file “c:\medicalreports.txt” –sort PatientID –search Jane
The program should print all the reports that contain the word Jane in any field, sorted by the second field.
The following command should print all the reports sorted by the Reason field.

Program1.exe –file “c:\medicalreports.txt” –sort Reason
And the following command should print reports that contain the word Jane, in the original order.

Program1.exe –file “c:\medicalreports.txt” -search “XR HAND SERIES”

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Read in lines from file.
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines("medicalreports.txt"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", line);

        }
        Console.Write("Input your search text: ");
        var text = Console.ReadLine();


    }
}
```

Just looking for something to head me in the right direction.

File looks like this

```
FacilityID:   12786
FacilityName: ACME Medical Center B
Facility Location: 
RecordID:            16615148-19056227-20536633-14140290
Patient:           Gav Brishen
Gender:            Male
PatientID:         475100
Laterality:        NA                  
Contrast:          NA                  
Reason:            Chest pain
ExamDate:          5/22/1998 9:19:00 PM
Ordering Ph:       Celes Kelbier
Radiologist:       Fias Talatheen
DOB:               5/13/1982
AccountNumber:     77739450
PACSID:            1298283
Procedure:         XR CHEST
Number of Films:   2
POS:               E
ReportStatus:      1

===================END OF RESULT===================

FacilityID:   12785
FacilityName: ACME Medical Center C
Facility Location: 
RecordID:            16616168-19057882-20538377-14141535
PatientID:         475099
AccountNumber:     77739451
PACSID:            1298306
Procedure:         XR CHEST
Number of Films:   2
Patient:           Zan Nire
Gender:            Male
DOB:               10/1/1986
Laterality:        NA                  
Contrast:          NA                  
Reason:            Chest pain
ExamDate:          5/22/1998 10:50:00 PM
Radiologist:       Nikana Meday
Ordering Ph:       Obran Opuurin
POS:               E
ReportStatus:      1

===================END OF RESULT===================

FacilityID:   12784
FacilityName: ACME Medical Center D
Facility Location: 
Number of Films:   5
Laterality:        NA                  
Contrast:          NA                  
Reason:            LUMBAR PAIN
ExamDate:          5/22/1998 2:54:00 PM
Radiologist:       Zentoo Jor
Ordering Ph:       Tumise Cornag
POS:               O
ReportStatus:      1
RecordID:            16612970-19051125-20531372-14137129
Patient:           Tiberius Cavi
Gender:            Female
PatientID:         475098
DOB:               1/16/1936
AccountNumber:     77739452
PACSID:            1298204
Procedure:         XR SPINE LUMBAR SERIES
```

Thanks

Comment: No it's fabricated for homework

Comment: What exactly is your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: OK good.  It looked real, but I see now it is for ACME Medical Center, which is a fake name.

Comment: I've tried searching the file for contains but I've had no success with it

Comment: The sample input appears to be only a single record, but your description of the app says it need to search across, and be able to return, multiple records.  Please provide a sample of multiple records.

Comment: This is a homework assignment and you have *nothing*, not even a start. Please go back to your textbook and *learn*. There are no shortcuts, programming isn't easy. You need to do this on your own and come here when you have problems. "I don't know" is not a problem we could solve. Pay more attention in class.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does the program print the contents of the text file?

Comment: Yes it prints the contents of the file formatted correctly. Just looking for some direction on how I can continue.

Comment: Read about passing/reading arguments to a program.Then Read about sorting a file based on a column and store the result in an array.Then read about search for a string in an array.Write these 3 small parts of the program and then ask for help.

Comment: Thanks just what I was looking for. Didn't want this done for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest first reading the entire file into a DataTable.  Then you can perform sorts and queries against it with standard SQL as if it were a database.  Just be sure to destroy it from memory when the application closes.

Here is an example for how to load it into a DataTable from the text file:

```
string txt = File.ReadAllText("medicalreports.txt");

//Separate records
string[] separator = { "===================END OF RESULT===================" };
string[] arrRecords = txt.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

DataTable table = new DataTable();

// Loop through records
for (int i = 0; i < arrRecords.Length; i++)
{
    string[] lines = arrRecords[i].Split('\n');

    DataRow row = new DataRow();
    // Loop through fields
    for (int j = 0; j < lines.Length; j++)
    {
        string[] keyValue = lines[j].Split(':');

        string field = keyValue[0].Trim();
        string value = keyValue[1].Trim();

        // Since not all records contain all columns, make sure this column exists. If not add it.
        if (!table.Columns.Contains(field))
        {
            table.Columns.Add(field);
        }

        row[field] = value;
    }
    table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the arguments the user passed, change your Main function like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //access the array
}
```

The array will contain the arguments passed in. For example if the user started your app with: `App.exe -id 2 -type 3`, the array contents will be: `["-id","2","-type","3"]`.